# how to protect url string which is created by GET in php

Tags: php, get

for a filemanagement i want to make an anchor for scanning a specific directory.

I use this echo for it:

```
echo   "<div class='urldir'>"
."<a href='?dir=".dirname($dir).'/'.basename($dir).'/'.$file."'>open dir</a>"
."</div>";
```

The dirname and basename give me the the right path to the directory.

this is the normal "root" directory for the users:

```
$dir = 'uploads/sfm/'.$UserID;
```

When i user created a folder in his root, he must be able to see the files in that folder.To change the directory and show  all the files in that directory, i use this

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";


$strArr = explode("=",$actual_link);
$CurrentPath = $strArr[1];


if(isset($_GET['dir'])) {
$dir = $CurrentPath;

}
```

So i read the dir from the url and the variable `$dir` changes

The problem: the url shows me a string like this:

`sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder`

When i type now in the url:

`sfm?dir=uploads/`

he shows me the files in uploads folder. This must be protected! 
Nobody should be able to see this.
And also this must be protected from view:
`sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/`

How can i achieve that?

By the way: the hash in the url is because i have the var $UserID md5 hashed
`md5($UserID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$protectedDirectories = array( 
                            array( 'uploads', 'sfm', $userId ) 
                        );

$directory = str_replace('\\','',$_GET['dir']);

$directory = trim($directory,'/');

$directory = preg_replace('#[\/]{1,}#','/',$directory);

$stats = false; // True = Protected , False = Cannot enter this directory.

$seperate = explode('/',$directory);

$cntSeperate = count( $seperate );

foreach($protectedDirectories as $pattern ){

    if( count( $pattern ) > $cntSeperate ){

        continue;

    }

    $innerStats = true;

    foreach( $pattern as $key => $val ){

        if( $seperate[ $key ] !== $val ){

            $innerStats = false;

            break;

        }

    }

    if( $innerStats == false ){

        continue;

    }

    $stats = true;

    break;

}

if( $stats == true ){

    // Access Granted

}else{

    // Access Not Granted

}
```

Now you can dynamically use your directory access grants. Each array means a pattern. Each array's value is a directory inside directories ( For example : array('uploads', 'sfm') means uploads/sfm )

Answer (score 1):

A sample solution is to grab the md5 directory using a regular expression.

Something like this:

```
$res = preg_match('/uploads\/sfm\/([a-f0-9]{32}).*/', $dir, $matches);

if (!$res || $matches[1] != md5($UserID)) {
   // user requested a directory he has no access to. Take additional 
   // actions, e.g. return HTTP status 403
   exit('No access here');
}
```

Comment: oke looks great. Just one more issue: when a user is looking in the root, the url is just: `http://example.coml/sfm` so if the url is like that, there must also be access

Comment: This is easy. If your dir var is empty, e.g. `if empty($_GET['dir']) ...` then allow access!